# Testing the contents between 2 mysql databases

Tags: php, mysql, testing

I've 2 databases with only 1 table in DB1 and 2 tables in DB2. Each record from DB1.table1 is split and stored in DB1.table1 and DB@.table2 respectively.

```
For example, DB1 has a table1 which looks like

        Student_Name   Id   Address   Attendance   Marks
        ------------   --   -------   ----------   -----
        John            1   90th st       70         90

The records that are transferred from DB1.table1 are stored in DB2.table and DB2.table2 in the following manner

DB2.table 1: Id   Student_Name   Address   
             --   ------------   -------
             1     John          90th st


DB2.table 2: Id   Attendance   Marks
             --   ----------   -----
             1     70            90
```

I want to write a test case to make sure all the data from DB1 is being copied to DB2. I've written some queries to find out if a record from DB1 is not copied to DB2. Apart from finding out the missing records, i also want to check column by column for each record to ensure that the values are the same in DB1 and DB2.

From the above example, i want to check for ID=1 if DB2.table1 Student_name=DB1.table1 Student_name, DB2.table1 Address=DB1.table1 Address, and so on..

What if i have 1000 columns? Should i write a long script to check each and every column? No. Whats the best way to do this kind of testing? Are there any tools which i can make use of or should i write down the script?

Comment: You are looking for database replication?

Comment: no..i want to test if each and every value is being copied properly or not

Answer (score 0):

This will find any `Id`s of rows from `db1.table1` that do not have matches in `db2.table1` and `db2.table2`.

It assumes that the columns are named the same in both tables, and any column that exists either `db2.table1` or `db2.table2` should have a matching column name in `db1.table1`. So if `db2.table2` has a column named `Foo`, `db1.table1` must also have a column named `Foo`. If `db2.table1` has a column named `Bar`, `db1.table1` must also have a column named `Bar`. If the column exists in `db2` but not in `db1`, you will get a MySQL error.

Hopefully this is what you were looking for!

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");

// connect with mysqli

// get a list of columns in db2.table1 and db2.table2
$columns = array();
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT table_name, column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'db2' AND table_name IN ('table1', 'table2')");
while ($row = $mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $columns[$row["table_name"]][] = "db1.table1.{$row["column_name"]} = db2.{$row["table_name"]}.{$row["column_name"]}";
}

$query = mysqli_query("
    SELECT db1.table1.Id
    FROM
        db1.table1
        LEFT JOIN db2.table1
            ON ". implode(" AND ", $columns["table1"]) ."
        LEFT JOIN db2.table2
            ON ". implode(" AND ", $columns["table2"]) ."
    WHERE
        db2.table1.Id IS NULL
        OR db2.table2.Id IS NULL
");

while (list($id) = mysqli_fetch_row($query)) {
    echo "ID {$id} does not match\n";
}
```

Comment: while trying your script i've encountered a common error `Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in....` but could to resolve it. i see that $query is already executed and still the error.

Comment: On both of the `mysqi_query` lines, add this before the semicolon: `or die(mysqli_error())`. This will tell you the error that it got. I wasn't really able to test the first query that gets the columns, and as a result I couldn't really test the second query with the implode stuff in there. Getting the error should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a union all and group by:

```
select Student_Name, Id, Address, Attendance, Marks,
       (case when max(which) = 'db1' then 'Missing in db2'
             when min(which) = 'db2' then 'Missing in db1'
        end) as why
from ((select 'db1' as which, Student_Name, Id, Address, Attendance, Marks
       from db1.table1 t
      ) union all
      (select 'db2' as which, t1.Student_Name, t1.id, t1.Address, t2.Attendance, t2.Marks
       from db2.table1 t1 join
            db2.table2 t2
            on t1.id = t2.id
      )
     ) u
group by Student_Name, Id, Address, Attendance, Marks
having count(distinct which) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Result of this query will give you number of rows in DB2 that are different from DB1, it also counts if row doesn't exist but it should. If the result is 0 everything is ok.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS difference
FROM
    DB1.table1 AS d1t1
    LEFT JOIN DB2.table1 AS d2t1
         USING (Id)
    LEFT JOIN DB2.table2 AS d2t2
         USING (Id)
WHERE
    (d1t1.Student_Name <> d2t1.Student_Name)
    OR (d1t1.Address <> d2t1.Address)
    OR (d1t1.Attendace <> d2t2.Attendace)
    OR (d1t1.Marks <> d2t2.Marks)
```